# OAuth2 authetication server and resource server using Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring Boot application.I am trying to implement OAuth2 authorization for that application. I have followed this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/ **Enabling the Authorization Server** part. Although I am successfully able to get access tokens from the auth-server, when I am trying to send those tokens to request my resource server, it errors **Unauthorized access** in the console.

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

Though I will separate both of the authorization server & resource server later, for initial purpose, single application for both will work.

```
@Configuration

@EnableAuthorizationServer

public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(Application.baseURL + "/user/register");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
        .and().csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

and for user authetication

```
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

@Loggable
private static Logger logger;

@Override
public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}

@Bean
UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsService() {

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)  throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            Session session = Hibernate.sessionFactory.openSession();
            try {
                UserPasswordDTO userPasswordDTO = new UserPasswordModel().getByEmailId(session, username);
                return new SimsmisUser(username, userPasswordDTO.hashedPassword, true, true, true, true, 
                        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER"), userPasswordDTO.userId);
            } 
            catch (InvalidIdException e) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(e.getMessage());
            }
            finally {
                if (session != null) {
                    try {
                        session.close();
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
}
```

How to communicate with the resource server with the access token?
Any example will help.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted any Resource Server configuration.

Try this tutorial as well for additional insights:

https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v